# Linear homogenous ODE of second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the ODE
  $$ (2x^2-x-1)y''-(4x^3+x-2)y'+(4x^3+2x^2-2x+2)y=0?$$
  I don't find it in the handbook by E. Kamke.

Comment: No clue. `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve[%282+x^2+-+x+-+1%29+y%27%27[x]+-+%284+x^3+%2B+x+-+2%29+y%27[x]+%2B+%284+x^3+%2B+2+x^2+-+2+x+%2B+2%29+y[x]+%3D%3D+0%2C+y[x]%2C+x]&dataset=`

Comment: @ eccstartup: Thank you. Maple also produces that.

Comment: Where did this ode come from?

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal : It belongs to math folklore.

Answer (score 3):

You can try as follows (sorry for my drop of details):

1. Find a particular solution of the ODE as first.  Try is: you can construct a specific solution of the form $y^*=e^{ax^2+bx}$, where $a,b$ are constants to be determined. The reason to choose this form is that the degree of the leading coefficient $2x^2-x-1$ is $2$, and that of the other two terms is $3$. Insert this $y^*$ into the ODE and you can find $a=1, b=0.$ Thus $y^*=e^{x^2}.$
2. Find the general solution by **the method of variation of constant**.  Assume the general solution is $y=C(x) y^*=C(x)e^{x^2}$, and substituting of it into ODE (then an ODE of Order-reducible appears)  and doing some calculation lead to $C(x)=C_1+C_2 x e^{-x(x-1)}$.  Then the general solution is $y=C_1e^{x^2}+C_2 xe^{x}.$

Comment: @ azhi :I vote up your answer, but I don't find it complete. The second step is wellknown.  The question remains open: why a particular solution is found in the form $e^{ax^2+bx}$? How CASes do it?

Comment: Executing the dsolve command of Maple at the printlevel:=65, I see that Maple classifies the ODE under consideration as the one of Kovacic type. The "Kovacic" googling brings me to a footballer Mateo Kovacic.

Comment: @user64494: http://www.sci.ccny.cuny.edu/~ksda/PostedPapers/jjk_algorithm_scan.pdf. I highly doubt they wanted you to use that rather than guessing at a solution and then using the first solution with reduction of order of VAC. Regards

Comment: @ Amzoti : I am very grateful to you for your rich-in-content answer. Could you transform your comment to an answer? In this case the question would be closed.